# JQuery Validation rules don't change dynamicaly

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I'm trying to change the rules (and messages) of a field dynamically. It seems to work but the first rules I define are the ones applying even when I redefine them.
I tried the method "resetForm()" without success, and also tried to add the rules like some answers to similar questions

```
$('input[name="textmsg"]').rules('add', rules);
```

but it throws an intern validate.js error.

---

My code works as follows:

```
var validationRules = {
    defaultField: { required: true },
    name: { required: true, minlength: 5, maxlength: 50 },
    birthDate: { required: true, date: true },
    phoneNumber: { required: true, maxlength: 20, digits: true }
};
```

[...]

```
$("#chatbox-form").submit(function(event)
{
    var valid = validateField(questionsInOrder[currentQuestion]);

    if (valid) {
        currentQuestion++;
    }
    askQuestion();
}
```

[...]

```
function validateField (question)
{
    var form = $("#chatbox-form");

    var rules = validationRules[question];
    if (typeof rules === "undefined") {
        rules = validationRules.defaultField;
    }

    var messages = validationMessages[question];
    if (typeof messages === "undefined") {
        messages = validationMessages.defaultField;
    }

    var validator = form.validate({
        rules: {
          textmsg: rules
        },
        messages: {
          textmsg: messages
        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            return true;
        },
        showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            if ((Object.keys(errorList).length) > 0) {
                errorMessage = errorList[0].message;
            }
        }
    });

    var valid = form.valid();

    validator.resetForm();

    return(valid);
}
```

Each time I submit an invalid response it asks again, and when it's a valid one it asks the next question. But the validation always apply the first set of rules, it doesn't refresh them (the field 'rules' and 'messages' are changing properly).

Comment: You have not shown us where you defined the variable called `rules` that you used within `$('input[name="textmsg"]').rules('add', rules)`.

Comment: Also, please note that the jQuery Validation Engine is something else entirely.  Edited.

Comment: I think a large part of your problem is the usage of a `submit()` handler.  Since the plugin is already taking care of handing the submit, yours has great potential to only cause problems.

Comment: The variable called 'rules' is just an object using the rules standard of JQuery validate.
About the usage of the submit handler, how else could I handle it? I'm not interested on submiting the form (and I need to do extra stuff on it).

Comment: The plugin contains [a callback function called `submitHandler`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#submithandler).  It is exactly what you're supposed to use instead of your own external `.submit()` handler, and the only reason it exists.  It only fires when the form is valid, so you would not need to test the form, and you can use it to block the default submit of the form, even after all validation.  It's very handy, and it would help you a great deal to learn how to leverage it properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution:

```
validator.destroy();
```

This destroys the instance (since *validate()* is the initialization for the plugin).
[Validator.destroy()](https://jqueryvalidation.org/Validator.destroy/).

---

An alternative would be using *rules('remove')* and *rules('add', rules)*. In this case we should call *validate()* only once at the beggining of the script.